# Data factory copy to dataverse/dynamics - how to update only

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, dataverse

I have been struggling to work out a way of doing a simple update only when copying data to the dataverse/dynamics.

The only write behaviour it seems to support is "Upsert".

[image]

However in my scenario I don't want to insert a row if it doesnt already exist.

I cant see a way to do this and would appreciate some help or ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Dataflows instead of copy data activity?

Comment: True I can see data flows has the option, but to me dataflows doesn't seem like the right solution for just updating a few rows at a time on a schedule. But perhaps I'm wrong, what do you think

Comment: Since the requirement is using only update, Dataflow helps better (you can specify conditions as well based on which you want to update). Since you are going to run a pipeline even to run the dataflow, you can use schedule triggers to achieve the job same as copy activity.

Comment: is it possible that you handle changes on source side. i.e adding a column on source side to tag rows that should be updated ? just a thought in case it helps

Comment: In the end here is what we did to get around this problem. We set up a custom entity (table) on the Dynamics side. We then inserted the data were were potentially interested in into the dynamics custom entity, then used another copy activity to get the data back out. This worked well as we needed to compare values between systems anyway, and it enabled us to apply business logic to the data in a staging database. Using this method we were able to determine which rows of data existed in both systems.